# Are there pre-upload hooks for Google repo?

Tags: git, repo

Are there hooks, like git hooks, for repo? I'd like to be able to run some simple tests on the branch I'm uploading before actually running repo upload.

Comment: What about `pre-push`

Comment: Where do you define this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you need is `pre-push` which lives, like all other git hooks, in `.git/hooks/`. You'll find a file named `pre-push.sample` containing a description of what the hook can do for you and an example.